# Java связующая таблица с таблицей с составным id

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Как мне связать таблицу, в которой id представлен в виде EmbedableId, с другой таблицей, связью manyToMany в hibernate?

Comment: Несколько способов описано в английской версии
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66827186/how-to-map-embeddable-that-contains-many-to-many